# define include page in colorbox iframe

Tags: php, jquery

i put in top of my include / external page any line for prevent Remote File Inclusion. this checked include file / extrenal load only in my index page . now when i load this (external page) in colorbox lightbox with iframe method this not work and i see blank page. if i remove this line worked ! how to fix this problem ? any way ?

top php page :

```
if (!defined('INDEX_ROOT') || (defined('INDEX_ROOT') && INDEX_ROOT != 'true')) die();
```

html & colorbox :

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){ $(".iframe").colorbox({ iframe:true,scrolling:false,width:665,height:600});});</script>

<a class="iframe" href="test.php">load frame</a>
```

thanks

Comment: What exactly should not work ? you have `die()` called .. you would exactly see a black page ...  share more light to your challenge ...

Comment: sure! `die()` show blank page if external page load in other. if external page include in my index ( define : INDEX_ROOT ) show page else show blank page . e.x . my domain/test.php ( blank page ) but if my domain/ you see test page ( after inluded in my index )

Answer (score 0):

This should be the structure of your system

`config.php`

```
//config.php
<?php

const INDEX_ROOT = "INDEX_ROOT";

?>
```

`protected.php`

```
<?php

if (! defined ( 'INDEX_ROOT' ) || (defined ( 'INDEX_ROOT' ) && INDEX_ROOT != 'true')) {
    die ();
}

function someFunction(){
    echo " Protected" ;
}   

?>
```

`sampleA.php`  // This would work

```
<?php

require 'config.php';
echo "Hello World"

?>
```

`sampleB.php`  // This would work

```
<?php

require 'config.php';
require 'protected.php';

echo "Hello Sample B" , someFunction() ;

?>
```

`sampleC.php`  // **This would not work**

```
<?php

require 'protected.php';
echo "Hello Sample C" , someFunction() ;

?>
```